# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

Há alguma coisa de errado com o ponteiro nesse programa, cujo objetivo é testar uma função que conta o número de caracteres de uma string. Por algum motivo ele não consegue ter acesso à memória para a qual ele aponta. Para esse programa eu criei um source e um header:

Código main(source):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mystring.h"

 int main() {

 char palavra[20];

 puts("Digite uma paravra qualquer:");
 fgets(palavra, sizeof(palavra), stdin);
 printf("%d", mystrlen(palavra));

 return 0;
}
```

Código do mystring.h que contém a função `mystrlen`(header):

```
int mystrlen(char *str) {
    int i = 0; // Contadora
    for (; (*str != '\0' || *str != '\n'); str++, i++);
    // Ponteiro percorre a string até o '\0' ou '\n'

    return i;
}
```

Abaixo, está o código de um exemplo semelhante que eu fiz. Esse exemplo, ao contrário do programa acima, funciona aqui.

```
int main() {

    char str[8] = "Exemplo", *ptr = str;
    int i;

    for (; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++, i++);

    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Qual pode ser o problema? Obrigado.

Comment: Para debugar falha de segmentação recomendo fortemente que você use um debugador que permita executar o programa um passo de cada vez, como o ddd ou gdb. Esses debugadores também vão te informat direitinho o número da linha com a falha de segmentação, o estado da pilha de chamadas e o valor das suas variáveis.

Comment: No segundo exemplo a variável `i` não foi inicializada. Isso pode ser fonte de comportamento imprevisível. btw, não sou muito fã desse estilo compacto de escrever C, a-la K&R. Acho que as coisas ficam mais claras com um comando por linha.

Comment: Bem, o curioso é que o segundo exemplo funciona...

Comment: Não tô entendendo... qual é o programa que dá pau? Por favor inclua o programa inteiro que você está rodando, sem quebrá-lo em partes.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para tentar deixar mais claro

Comment: in English: this line: `(*str != '\0' || *str != '\n');` has a problem.  with the `||` one or the other of the expressions will always be `true`  the line should be: `(*str != '\0' && *str != '\n');`

Comment: in English: in the second posted code, the variable `i` is not initialized suggest replace: `int i;` with `int i=0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um erro no seu loop. Você tá usando OU ao invés de E:

```
// versão atual
(*str != '\0' || *str != '\n')

// versão correta
(*str != '\0' && *str != '\n')
```

O resultado disso é que a condição do loop é sempre verdadeira.

Comment: Engraçado, eu já tinha pensado em substituir o operador OU pelo E, mas eu achei que nesse caso não faria diferença (continue no loop caso o valor do endereço seja diferente de `\0` OU diferente de `\n`). Não achei que esse seria o problema porque o erro no acesso ao endereço de memória se dava exatamente na linha do loop, então eu pensei que o problema era que, de alguma forma, ele não conseguia ter acesso ao primeiro endereço da `string`. De qualquer forma, fiz essa alteração e deu certo aqui, obrigado.

Comment: eu diria que esse é um argumento a favor de escrever um comando por linha ao invés de tentar escrever esses loops super espertos. :) As mensagens de erro fica mais claras.